# How can i fill my list from rad grid view?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a **telerik** grid view and i want to fill my list with one of the columns, but when i check my list it's empty.

Here is my code

```
foreach (int item in _MyAmount)
{
    _MyAmount.Add(item);
}
```

I know it is not related to my grid view.
Can you teach me how to do that?

Comment: You don't need RadGridView for it... Why you can't fill it from source that was used to fill grid?

Comment: @Spawn cuase i use grid view for filling

Comment: Ok, WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @Spawn winform,thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

So, on form we have some RadGridView and Button. To make value type in Column as int you can use DataType property.

```
List<int> someList = new List<int>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var row in radGridView1.Rows)
        // 0 - first column
        someList.Add((int)row.Cells[0].Value);
}
```